# How can I edit the header and footer of Travelify Wordpress Theme?

Tags: wordpress

I want to modify the Travelify Wordpress Theme.

I want to put some options like `Home|Contact Us|Search` on the header.

I want to put an image on the footer.

**Question**

How can I achieve these changes to the theme?

Comment: After consulting the documentation for the theme (https://colorlib.com/wp/support/travelify/) it appears that some features you want are not part of the theme by default and need custom code to work. How comfortable are you with PHP? You would need to provide the code for the header and footer for someone to be able to help show you where to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a navigation menu on header, you must setting your menu first.

Setting your navigation menu on appearance>menu

You can setting your footer on appearance>widgets

Try SiteOrigin Widgets bundle plugin for more Widgets on your wordpress.

And for a custom CSS, I use SiteOrigin CSS.

Answer (score 0):

First go to **'wordpress/wp-content/theme'** folder and generate an directory with similar name as your theme name.Let say theme name is **'travelify'** then use child theme name as **'travelify-child'**.
Now go to **'travelify-child'** folder and add two files **i.e.(style.css and functions.php)**
Now open **style.css** from parent theme **i.e.'travelify'**
copy all css code and paste into new style.css in **'travelify-child'** folder.
**don't forget to change theme name,description,text domain.**
**Add 'Template: travelify' in to style.css**.....you can add it after anyline in header like after 'Author URI'.
Now save this style.css and **open functions.php** in **'travelify-child'** foder
and paste **below code** into **functions.php**

```
<?php
add_action( 'init' , 'remove_copyright' , 15 );
function remove_copyright() {
remove_action( 'travelify_footer', 'travelify_footer_info', 30 );
}
add_action( 'travelify_footer' , 'new_footer_info' , 30 );
function new_footer_info() {
   $output = '<div class="copyright">Copyright © 2016 Your website name.Powered by Wordpress.
   <a href="https://codex.wordpress.org/" target="_blank">Wordpress</a></div>';
   echo $output;
}
?>
```